# Concatenate string in statement that assigns a variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to convert SQL Server procedure to PostgreSQL.

In the SQL Server procedure There are statements like below

> SET @val = '(' + @someval + ')'

So in postgresql I wrote as below

> SET val = '(' || someval || ')';

But the above statement giving error at ||

Any body can please tell me where am I making mistake

Comment: Can you share the whole procedure with us?  It might not be the concatenation itself, but rather the where that statement is being interpreted.

Comment: Please read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK, SET statement in PostgreSQL used for [changing configutation parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html), for variable assignment just use `:=`:

```
val := '(' || someval || ')';
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9bf92/1)</kbd>**